# $watch is not working on model created by ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs

My html code:

```
<accordion-group  ng-repeat="container in containers" is-open="container.open"> 
------
</accordion-group>
```

My controller:

```
$scope.$watch('container.open',
    function(value) {
        if ( value ) {
            $scope.getListFilesOfcontainer(container.name);
        }
    }
);
```

I am getting error as `cannot read name of undefined`.

Answer (score 0):

`ng-repeat` create a new scope foreach iteration. 
In your example `container` will be available to the elements inside ng-repeat. It will not be available in controller.

Comment: Can you create a plunker/fiddle for this?

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't that be:

```
$scope.$watch('container.open',
    function(value) {
        if ( value ) {
            $scope.getListFilesOfcontainer($scope.container.name);
        }
    }
);
```